# SSIS is not inserting all rows

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have an issue with **VS SSDT 2017, SSIS Express Edition**. My Source is Oracle 12G and Destination is SQL Server 2017. My package consist of simple Data Load task; Source Connection and Destination connection. And data is coming from SQL script. Using OLE DB connection. Count in source says 238674 rows but SSIS loads and inserts only 144254 rows and there is no any error. Package ends with success (green check marks).
Destination table has no issues with types or something. All types and sizes are identical with source. When I delete most of the columns from SQL script and load only 1 or 2 columns it extracts and inserts all 238674 rows. But when there are more columns (8-9 columns), inserted row number is getting smaller.

Comment: Which Oracle OLEDB connection do you use? Try using: Oracle Provider for OLE DB
Also try using fast load in your destination if you're not

Comment: Can you start with 1 or 2 columns and then work up to see which column is causing the problem? Sounds like you're getting rows ignored or truncated. Also, do you exactly how many rows you're expecting from your source procedure?

Comment: @holder for source conn I am using Oracle Provider for OLE DB. And I tried both load and fast load. Result is same.

Comment: @JimJimson Count(*) returns 238674 rows in source, but only 144254 is being extracted and inserted to destination. When I change script and remove some of the columns, inserted number is increases to something 226000 after a certain number of columns removed from script, it extracts all 238674 rows. Seems like it is related with the total volume of extracted data.

Comment: My hunch is it's going to be some values violating some constraint. I'd advise cutting back the columns until it loads all the records and then add columns 1 at a time until the rowcount drops. Then take each offending column out to see if it's one or more column causing the problem.

Comment: @Nail_Mustafa What is the script code that you are using/referencing?

Comment: @JWeezy Did you mean SQL script? Its too long to post it here

Comment: @Nail_Mustafa By any chance, are you using Oracle Teradata connections on the most recent version of SSDT (15.8.2)? Per Microsoft's change log, the current version does not support this, you must use 15.8. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/changelog-for-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by this way:
1. Open SSDT as Administrator 
2. Use ODBC Source (32bit) for Oracle Source connection
3. Use SQL Server Destination for MSSQL 2017 connection

Everything works fine in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Set  DataFlow setting AutoAdjustBufferSize = True same issue solved for me .