# SSIS not inserting all rows from ODBC (oracle) to SQL Server 2019

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2019

I have an issue with migration to SQL Server 2019.

My source is Oracle and my destination is Microsoft SQL Server 2019. My package consists of a simple data load task; ODBC Source Connection (Oracle) and OLE DB destination connection (for SQL Server 2019). And data is coming from an Oracle SQL script.

**Issue**: the package is successfully executing but not inserting all rows. If the Oracle SQL script is returning 100 rows, the insert is happening for 80 of them only with no errors or warning.

Have tried SSDT 2017 (15.8, 15.9.3, 15.9.7) and Visual Studio Community 2019 but facing the same issue.

Note - this issue is resolved when we are changing `TargetServerVersion` from 2019 to 2017 or lower, but when the package is run through the job from SQL Server 2019 the count is back to less.

As we need to migrate a lot of packages, we need a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513189/ssis-is-not-inserting-all-rows

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-connection-managers-ole-db-vs-odbc-vs-ado-net/